# Connected scheme which admits a monomorphism to an affine Noetherian scheme of finite Krull dimension

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, schemes, affine-schemes

Let $Y$ be a Noetherian  affine scheme of finite Krull dimension. Let $X$ be a connected scheme and suppose there exists a monomorphism (in the category of schemes) $X \to Y$. Then is it true that $\dim X \le \dim Y$ ?